# map on the lower level key of a nested object

Tags: javascript

I had posted this question earlier but someone deleted with [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)
as possible answer. This is not helping me since a) The key 'date' is spread across several names, b)The objects comprises on arrays & objects & c) The depth at which the key 'date' is present can change.

Hence posting the question again.

I have a JS object as below

```
const bb = {
  Harry: {
    details: [
      {
        cat: "Life",
        values: [
          {
            date: "2021-08-02",
            level: 77.6,
          },
          {
            date: "2021-08-03",
            level: 79.1,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  Barry: {
    details: [
      {
        cat: "Logic",
        values: [
          {
            date: "2021-08-02",
            level: 77.6,
          },
          {
            date: "2021-08-03",
            level: 79.1,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

I also have a variable defined for parsing the dates const dateParse = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")

I want to parse all the dates in the object. Since the 'date' is few levels below in the object, I am not able to figure this out. How do I go about it?

The expected output is

```
const bb = {
  Harry: {
    details: [
      {
        cat: "Life",
        values: [
          {
            date: Mon Aug 02 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
            level: 77.6,
          },
          {
            date: Tue Aug 03 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
            level: 79.1,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  Barry: {
    details: [
      {
        cat: "Logic",
        values: [
          {
            date: Mon Aug 02 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
            level: 77.6,
          },
          {
            date: Tue Aug 03 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
            level: 79.1,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: There should be a way to parse the date before the chart is rendered in the D3 itself. This will save extra iterations on your input object

Comment: @ihimv D3 indeed has that option but I am not able to 'locate' the date key (hence the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to loop through the objects, select the date node and execute

`(new Date(datestring)).toString()`

This will generate the date as specified in your output.

```js
const bb = { Harry: { details: [{cat: "Life",values: [{date: "2021-08-02",level: 77.6},{date: "2021-08-03",level: 79.1}]}]},Barry: {details: [{cat: "Logic",values: [{date: "2021-08-02",level: 77.6},{date: "2021-08-03",level: 79.1}]}]}};
Object.values(bb).forEach((value) => {
  value.details.forEach((detail) => {
    detail.values.forEach((value) => {
      value.date = (new Date(value.date)).toString();
    })
  })
});
console.log(bb);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect. I only removed `.toString()` since I wanted the 'date' to be the date object itself.

Comment: Cool. I thought it was a string

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse all the nested `date` keys, you can do it recursively using the below functions

```
const bb = { Harry: { details: [{cat: "Life",values: [{date: "2021-08-02",level: 77.6},{date: "2021-08-03",level: 79.1}]}]},Barry: {details: [{cat: "Logic",values: [{date: "2021-08-02",level: 77.6},{date: "2021-08-03",level: 79.1}]}]}};

function traverseArray(inputArray) {
  for (const arrayValue of inputArray) {
    traverseObject(arrayValue);
  }
}

function traverseObject(inputObject) {
  for (const key in inputObject) {
    const value = inputObject[key];
    const valueType = typeof(value);
    if (valueType == "object") {
      traverseObject(value);
    } else if (valueType == "array") {
      traverseArray(value);
    } else if (key == "date") { // since I want to parse only date keys
      inputObject[key] = 'd3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d") - Parse date here';
    }
  }
}
        
traverseObject(bb);
console.log(bb);
```